# zsh command not found, likely path issue

Tags: shell, path, zsh

I recently switched to zsh from bash and couldn't install any npm bundles. I found some stack overflows telling me to reset the path in my zsh profile, which I did. Now I can't execute any commands, including `bundle install`.

Things I've tried:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export path
```

from the command line

Modifying ~/.zshrc to add

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH
```

, then saving and restarting iTerm.

When I `echo $PATH`, this is what I get: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Restarting my terminal after each change, I still get: `zsh: command not found: bundle`

Help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: I tried switching to another computer and cloning the repo down and am getting the same error when I try to bundle install. If I switch to another repo on the other computer (where I didn't mess with the path), bundle install works. On my initial computer (with the path edits), none of the repos allow bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where is your bundle program (you can use `locate` or `find`) ? It can be in another directory that is not in your path. For example, it can be in `/usr/local/bin` so you should add this path to your `$PATH`.